# How do I get query for products added in last 30 days (HSQLDB)

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

Before anyone comments, I must use HSQLDB RDBMS; it's for university java project. My question is how would I get list of invoices created in last 30 days

```
CREATE TABLE Invoices(
    rid INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    invoicedate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);
```

Comment: What have you tried? If you have a date field it should not be that hard to get all entries where `invoicedate >= somedate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use HSQL's [dateadd function](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#bfc_current_datetime):

```
select  *
from    Invoices
where   invoicedate > dateadd('day', -30, CURRENT_DATE)
```

Comment: HSQLDB dateadd params are in the opposite order:  `dateadd('day', -30, CURRENT_DATE)`. Can also use `invoicedate > CURRENT_DATE - 30 DAY`

Comment: @fredt: Thanks, edited in the answer.  I assumed `<field>` in the documentation meant the column, but the following line reads `<field> ::= 'yy' | 'year' | 'mm' | ....`